# Extending express() app in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, express, extends

I'm using Express MVC in node.js.

It's main objcect is `express()` aliased to `app`:

```
var express = require('express');

app = express();
```

How to extend `express()` with my method?

I want to use my methods like `app.doSomething()` along with predefined ones such as `app.set()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.dosomething = function() { console.log('do') }
app.dosomething();
```

Do you want this?